# Tornado AsyncHTTPClient HTTP persistent connection support (HTTP keep-alive)

Tags: python, tornado

Does tornado's **AsyncHTTPClient** support HTTP persistent connection (HTTP keep-alive)? If yes, is there any sample code doing that?

I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: I assume you've read this discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804013/tornado-web-persistent-connections.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested on how to do persistent HTTP requests (client side), not on how to handle them server side. And if I understand correctly your reference points to the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of October 2012, Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient does NOT support persistent HTTP connections.

However, there's a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/pull/328) to add it.